# Why doesn't Perl 5 tell you the name of the variable when it complains about uninitialized values?

Tags: perl

Why doesn't Perl 5 give me the name of the variable it is complaining about?

```
perl5.8.9 -we 'my $u; print "$u\n"'
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 9):

It [has](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Use-of-uninitialized-value%25s) since version 5.10 which was released in 2007, it is time to upgrade ([5.12.2](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2-RC1/) is coming out shortly).

```
perl5.10.0 -we 'my $u; print "$u\n"'
Use of uninitialized value $u in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
```

Comment: @user275455 Somebody had to have the knowledge and the time and the inclination to make it do that. Its non-trivial for Perl to figure out what triggered the warning as you can see by looking at the patch which implemented it. http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/29489e7c741791873ea464cb7e13d2b5a19577a7